# What could be a monotonic, continuous and smooth function with these conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I am looking for a smooth, continuous and monotonic function that satisfies these conditions:

$f(0) = 0$,
$f'(0) = 1$,

$f(m) = 1$,
$f'(m) = 1/m$, where $m > 1$ is a fixed real number.

Also, it would be great if the function has a control parameter that allows increasing or decreasing the interval with high derivatives ($f' \simeq 1$) with respect to with the interval with low derivatives ($f'\simeq 1/m$).

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is a _monolithic_ function?

Comment: It isn't clear whether or not $m$ is fixed or even an integer.

Comment: Since there are are four constraints, we need a function with four parameters. Assume the function is of the form:
$$
f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
$$
Solving the resulting linear system of four equations with four unknowns yields:
$$
f(x)= \left(\dfrac{m-1}{m^3}\right) x^3 - \left(\dfrac{2m-2}{m^2}\right) x^2 + x
$$
**Note:** This is only monotonic for $1 < m < 4$.

Comment: @Adriano: Thanks. However, I have cases where $m>10000$.

Answer (score 0):

This function cannot exist.

By hypothesis, $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. We are looking for a function with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.

If we ignore the constraints that $f(m)=1$ and $f'(m)=1/m$ with $m>1$, we can use the function $f(x)=x$, which is smooth, monotonic and satisfies the first two constraints.

Now, if $f(m)=1$, $\forall m$, (note that it doesn't matter which $m$ we fix), then this means the function *must* be constant. If the function is constant, then $f'(m)=0$ for any fixed $m$ we choose, so the fourth constraint that $f'(m)=1/m$ is actually impossible.

I am not sure if this was quite what OP had in mind. Note that we didn't even need smoothness of $f$, as we have shown the stronger result that no $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ function can satisfy these constraints.